# Text User Interface, cannot get a method to work

Tags: java, text, interface

I have an assignment to carry out using BlueJ where I am given a class called HW4CustomerList and I must create a Text-Based UI for it. The class I have to create is called CustomerTUI and contains a method called addCustomer which adds a new Customer object of mine to an ArrayList. This method in particular is what I am stuck with. The class specification says that I cannot take any parameters (i.e. a no-args method). In previous work we have used the BlueJ 'method box' to interact with objects and add them to ArrayLists, however I do not know if this can be used in this particular instance. Please find below my code so far for CustomerTUI and the code for the Customer class and HW4CustomerList class. Many thanks in advance.

CustomerTUI class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomerTUI
{
private HW4CustomerList customerList;
private Scanner myScanner;

public CustomerTUI()
{
    customerList = new HW4CustomerList();
    myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public void menu()
{
    int command;
    boolean running = true;

    while(running)
    {
        displayMenu();
        command = getCommand();
        execute(command);
    }
}

private void addCustomer()
{
    customerList.addCustomer();
}

private void displayMenu()
{
    System.out.println("            CustomerList program         ");
    System.out.println("=========================================");
    System.out.println("|Add a customer to the list..........[1]|");
    System.out.println("|Get number of customers.............[2]|");
    System.out.println("|Remove a customer from the list.....[3]|");
    System.out.println("|Show all customer details...........[4]|");
    System.out.println("|Show a specific customers details...[5]|");
    System.out.println("|Quit................................[6]|");
    System.out.println("=========================================");
}

private void execute(int command)
{
    if(command == 1)
    {
        addCustomer();
    }

    else if(command == 2)
    {
        getNumberOfCustomers();
    }

    else if(command == 3)
    {
        removeCustomer();
    }

    else if(command == 4)
    {
        showAllCustomers();
    }

    else if(command == 5)
    {
        showCustomer();
    }

    else if(command == 6)
    {
        quitCommand();
    }

    else
    {
        unknownCommand(command);
    }
}

private int getCommand()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the command of the function you wish to use: ");
    int command = myScanner.nextInt();
    return command;
}

private void getNumberOfCustomers()
{
    if(customerList.getNumberOfCustomers() == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("We have " + customerList.getNumberOfCustomers() + " customer.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("We have " + customerList.getNumberOfCustomers() + " customers.");
    }
}

private void quitCommand()
{
    System.out.println("The program is now closing down...");
    System.exit(0);
}

private void removeCustomer()
{
    String accNo;

    System.out.println("Enter the account number of the customer you wish to remove: ");
    accNo = myScanner.next();
    if (customerList.removeCustomer(accNo) == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Customer with account number " + accNo + " was successfully removed.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Customer with account number " + accNo + " was NOT successfully removed.");
        System.out.println("Please try again.");
    }
}

private void showAllCustomers()
{
    customerList.getAllCustomers();
}

private void showCustomer()
{
    String accNo;

    System.out.println("Enter the account number of the customer you wish to view: ");
    accNo = myScanner.next();
    if(customerList.getCustomer(accNo) == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not find customer with account number " + accNo + ".");
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

private void unknownCommand(int command)
{
    System.out.println("Command number " + command + " is not valid. Please try again.");
}
}
```

HW4CustomerList class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HW4CustomerList
{
private ArrayList<Customer> customers;    

public HW4CustomerList()
{
   customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
}

public void addCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    customers.add(customer);
}

public int getNumberOfCustomers()
{
    return customers.size();
}

public boolean getCustomer(String accountNumber)
{
   for(Customer customer : customers)
   {
       if(accountNumber.equals(customer.getAccountNumber()))
       {
          customer.printCustomerDetails();
          return true;
      }
  }
  return false;
}


public void getAllCustomers()
{
    for(Customer customer : customers)
    {
        customer.printCustomerDetails();
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}


public boolean removeCustomer(String accountNumber)
{
     int index = 0;
     for (Customer customer: customers)
     {
          if (accountNumber.equals(customer.getAccountNumber()))
        {
            customers.remove(index);
            return true;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is create a new Customer object in your addCustomer() method. This would probably require getting additional details:

```
public void addCustomer()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter customer name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    //any additional details
    Customer customer = new Customer(name, otherParams);
    customers.add(customer);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have tried this, one paramater is a customers Street name, and another is their town name, and using the scanner seems to mess up when I enter a string with a space in (i.e. "North Street"). Many thanks for your help though!

Comment: Are you using nextLine() for the street name? If so, what's going wrong with it?

Comment: When I type in the street name (for example 'North Street' (without quote marks)) it will put the word 'North' into my streetName variable, and the word 'Street' into my townName variable, which messes the whole process up

Comment: System.out.println("Enter customer's first name: ");
 String fName = myScanner.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Enter customer's second name: ");
 String sName = myScanner.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Enter customer's account number: ");
 String accNo = myScanner.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Enter customer's street name: ");
 String streetName = myScanner.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Enter customer's town name: ");
 String townName = myScanner.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Enter customer's post code: ");
 String postCode = myScanner.nextLine();